# During the request - response process, what goes behind the scene when a Yii -2.0 application is run()?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to make a simplest and a very basic request-response system in php, similar to as in Yii-2.0. For that I was reading inside the basic\web\index.php there is:

```
$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->run();
```

I dug deeper, but couldn't figure out how the process is carried out.

**Here is what I found:**

the `run()` method in yii\web\application has this (excluding the triggers):

```
$response = $this->handleRequest($this->getRequest());
$response->send();
return $response->exitStatus;
```

handleRequest is just an abstract function yet,

```
abstract public function handleRequest($request);
```

So I basically don't understand how this code is returning a response?

**UPDATE**:

As answered here is the `handleRequest` function for quick referene:

```
public function handleRequest($request)
    {
        if (empty($this->catchAll)) {
            list ($route, $params) = $request->resolve();
        } else {
            $route = $this->catchAll[0];
            $params = $this->catchAll;
            unset($params[0]);
        }
        try {
            Yii::trace("Route requested: '$route'", __METHOD__);
            $this->requestedRoute = $route;
            $result = $this->runAction($route, $params);
            if ($result instanceof Response) {
                return $result;
            } else {
                $response = $this->getResponse();
                if ($result !== null) {
                    $response->data = $result;
                }
                return $response;
            }
        } catch (InvalidRouteException $e) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('yii', 'Page not found.'), $e->getCode(), $e);
        }
    }
```

i'm in a process to figure out the whole process. will post as an answer as soon as I get a full hold of it. Probably we shall make a better flowchart than Yii documentation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-overview.html) and take a look at this :
[image]

About [`\yii\web\Application::handleRequest()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-application.html#handleRequest()-detail) :
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.7/framework/web/Application.php#L72

About [`\yii\web\Response::send()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#send()-detail) :
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.7/framework/web/Response.php#L305